# 'module' object has no attribute 'STARTUPINFO'

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, python-2.7

my program have a code:

---

```
info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
info.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE
```

---

and my OS is kali linux.
when I run program in python 2 or 3 has error:

---

```
AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'STARTUPINFO'
```

---

please help me.
thanks.

Comment: How to fix this when developing on linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `STARTINFO` class is only available on Windows. Clearly stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#windows-popen-helpers):

> The `STARTUPINFO` class and following constants are only available on
>   Windows.

Comment: which class is for kali linux??  I want to use the ping command contained in kali linux

Comment: @siamakafra There isn't a corresponding class.

Comment: output = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-n', '1', '-w', '500', str(all_hosts[i])], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                  startupinfo=info).communicate()[0]